# Algorithm to find out level

Tags: algorithm

Let's say I have following hierarchy of levels:

- level 1

  - stage 1
  - stage 2
  - stage 3
- level 2

  - stage 4
  - stage 5
  - stage 6
- level 3

  - stage 7
  - stage 8
  - stage 9

How can I find the level number programmatically if I know the stage number, as stage 5 has level 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following formula to find what level you're on based on a given stage:

```
level = ceil(stage / 3)
```

Examples:

```
ceil(5 / 3) = 2
ceil(9 / 3) = 3
ceil(1 / 3) = 1
```

Though, this answer only works if each level has **exactly** 3 stages.

Comment: *Never* make an assumption like that in production code.  It will come back to bite you...

Comment: @EricJ. I understand that which is why I pointed that out at the end. Also, this assumption works with his provided example. If he says something different I'll adjust my answer, but for now it solves his problem.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully you have a pointer up to the parent node.

Keep following that pointer up until there is no parent node.  You have found the root node.  Count how many times you have to follow a pointer up to the parent to get your depth.

Answer (score 0):

Well

If you are using python it is very easy.

```
>>> d = { 'level 1' : [ 'stage 1', 'stage 2', 'stage 3' ], 
...       'level 2' : [ 'stage 4', 'stage 5', 'stage 6' ],
...       'level 3' : [ 'stage 7', 'stage 7', 'stage 9' ],
...     }
>>> for key, val in d.items():
...     if 'stage 5' in val:
...             print key
```

Thank You